# how can I update an array which has a different type and secondary array has different type in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs, typescript

```
let user: { id: number, name: string }[] = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "ABC" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "XYZ" }
];

let dataList: { id: number, name: string, address: string , pin: string, comment: string}[] = [];
```

If I want to move the user data array to dataList array how can I do that?

If I use map function then do I need to initialize empty data for other fields for dataList?

Comment: The types are clearly not assignable to one another because `dataList` has additional properties. Bascially you have two options. 1: Mark `address`, `pin`, `comment` as optional. 2: `.map()` the array and define all required values.

Comment: If you use map you'll have to set `address`, `pin`, `comment` as empty strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) return an array, so you simply

```
dataList=user.map((x:any)=>({
  id:x.id,
  name:x.name,
  address:...
  ...rest of properties...
})
```

In "strict mode", if you don't want add all the properties with a default value you should use some like

```
dataList=user.map((x:any)=>({
  id:x.id,
  name:x.name,
  address:...
  ...not all the properties...
} as { id: number, name: string, 
       address: string , pin: string, 
       comment: string})
```

See the implicit convert "as". Generally you use an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
export interface dataModel
     { id: number, name: string, 
       address: string , pin: string, 
       comment: string}
     }

dataList:dataModel=user.map((x:any)=>({
  id:x.id,
  name:x.name,
} as dataModel)
```

Yes, a "map" if "somelike"

```
data=[]
for (let i=0;i<user.length;i++)
   data.push({
       id:user[i].id
       name:user[i].name
   })
return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I need to initialize empty data.

Here is a simple example.

```
let user: { id: number, name: string }[] = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "ABC" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "XYZ" }
];

let dataList: { id: number, name: string, address: string, pin: string, comment: string }[] = user.map(item => {
    return {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        address: "",
        pin: "",
        comment: ""
    };
});
```